# Creating multiple SchedulerFactoryBean in Quartz

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, quartz-scheduler

I have run into a problem where I have two classes extending `QuartzJobBean`. The problem I am facing is to create two `SchedulerFactoryBean`. I did my research and found that setting the property `schedulerName` solves the problem. This did not work for me. I used `@Qualifier` also. If I create the two beans of `SchedulerFactoryBean` , Spring doesn't know which scheduler to refer to. I have two CronTriggers.

Code:

```
<!--
   <bean name="quartzSchedulerR" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.task.QuartzScheduler" />
        <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="rRSImpl" value-ref="rRSService"  />
                <entry key="SRObject" value-ref="SRObject"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean> 

        <bean id="cronTriggerR"
            class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">

            <property name="jobDetail" ref="quartzSchedulerR" />
            <property name="cronExpression" value="0 30 12 ? * MON *" />

    </bean>

        <bean id="quartzScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" lazy-init="false">
        <property name="schedulerName" value="scheduleOne"/>
        <property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
            <map>
            <entry key="rSchedulerServiceImpl" value-ref="rSchedulerServiceImpl"></entry>
            </map>
        </property>
        <property name="jobDetails">
           <list>
              <ref bean="quartzSchedulerR" />
           </list>
        </property>

        <property name="triggers">
            <list>
            <ref bean="cronTriggerR" />
            </list>
        </property>

        </bean> -->

        <bean id ="quartzScheduler" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean" lazy-init="false">
            <property name="schedulerContextAsMap">
                    <map>
                    <entry key="rSSImpl" value-ref="rSSImpl"></entry>
                    </map>
            </property>
        </bean>


        <bean id="jobDetailFactory" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetBeanName">
            <idref local="jobDetail" />
        </property>

        </bean>

        <bean id="jobDetail" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean" scope="prototype">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.scheduler.SMTPMailJob " />

         <property name="jobDataAsMap">
            <map>
              <entry key="rSSeImpl" value-ref="rSSImpl" />
              <entry key="fUtil" value-ref="fUtil" />
              <entry key="rService" value-ref="rService" />
              <entry key="fusion" value-ref="fusion"/>
              <entry key="fcproperties" value-ref="fcproperties"/>
             </map>
          </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="jobTriggerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ObjectFactoryCreatingFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetBeanName">
            <idref local="jobTrigger" />
        </property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="jobTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean"
        scope="prototype">
        </bean>
```

Currently I comment out the first scheduler and the application works as expected. But if I uncomment it, the second scheduler stops working. Any workaround for this issue.. ? Any help is appreciated.

**EDIT:** There is no error but I know that the job isn't scheduled. The error is basically that spring doesn't find a unique bean for `com.quartz.Scheduler` when both the `SchedulerFactoryBean` are defined. Basically how to configure multiple `SchedulerFactoryBean` for totally isolated classes.. ?

Comment: What stops... What happens.. Post some logs/stacktraces.

Answer (score 0):

Please can you explain why do you need two scheduarfactorybeans. 
As per spring doc, FactoryBean that creates and configures a Quartz Scheduler, manages its lifecycle as part of the Spring application context, and exposes the Scheduler as bean reference for dependency injection.

This means you cant have multiple instances of the bean.

Also as per your code you are trying to schedule multiple jobs which can be done using one schedularFactoryBean.  Create Multiple job beans and their corresponding triggers and add them as list to the schedular factoryBean. All the triggers will be invoked as per configuration irrespective of whether it is a cron trigger or simple trigger.